# Polymorphic Paperclip overwriting files with the same names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file, paperclip, interpolation, polymorphism

in Rails using the Polymorphic version of Paperclip, the default saving technique means that files with the same name overwrite each other. Including the :id in the path and URL doesn't work as it just overwrites the earlier file with the old :id.

I've tried interpolations using a time-stamp, but it just looks for the current time when being shown the image (plus as I have multiple thumbnails it takes longer than a second, therefore the images have different stamps).

```
Paperclip.interpolates :uniqueid do |attachment, style|
  Time.now.to_i.to_s
end
```

Also tried using a hex number, but it iterates through for each thumb, thus breaking as there's a new hex value each time.

```
Paperclip.interpolates :uniqueid do |attachment, style|
  ActiveSupport::SecureRandom.hex(3)
end
```

As it's the Polymorphic version, and thus has it's own model, I don't know how to access the values from the parent model (in this case "Post").
Variations on the code below all throw up "undefined method" errors.

```
Paperclip.interpolates :user_id do |attachment, style|
  current_user.id
end
```

Sorry if it seems a newbie question, but it's well document for the traditional Paperclip, but nothing is out there for the Polymorphic fork.

Answer (score 0):

How about including **`:class`** in the `:path` for `has_attached_file` ?

```
has_attached_file :attachment,
  :path => ":rails_root/attachments/:class/:id/:attachment/:basename.:extension",
  :url => "downloads/:id/:title.:extension"
```

Comment: What if you have multiple files for the same class and model instance?